# Shortcut Technique for finding Raised Binomials with Imaginary Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the Value of $(1+i)^5$ where $i$ is an imaginary number.

The answer is $-4\cdot (1+i)$

We can always multiply them manually; but $i$ was wondering if there are any math tricks to quickly finding the answer. For the exam we might be given $(1+i)^{99}$ or some other integer $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the polar form for imaginary numbers we easily get
$(1+i)^5 = (\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4})^5 = \sqrt{2}^5 e^{5i\pi/4} = \sqrt{2}^5\left(-\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right) = -\sqrt{2}^4(1+i)= -4(1+i)$.

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique is to write the complex number $z=a + b i$ in exponential form, $$z= r e^{i \theta}.$$. To do this notice that $$r= \sqrt{a^2+b^2},$$ and $$\theta = \arctan{b/a}.$$ The usefulness of this is that taking powers turns into multiplication of exponents:

$$z^n = (r e^{i \theta})^n = r^n e^{ i n \theta}.$$

Once you've taken the power you can then reverse the process to write the solution in rectangular form by noting that

$$ a = r \cos{\theta}, $$
$$ b = r \sin{\theta}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As other users have suggested, [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula) may be your best bet in terms of efficiency, but you can also apply the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) in place of "multiplying manually." Summing up the real and imaginary terms would be a hassle for large exponents.